# Gradlew on Android device?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, terminal-emulator

Can I run the gradlew command from my android phone on the terminal emulator with root access to compile an android project and generate an APK?
If yes where would the Android SDK be on phone?
What would be other ways to create an APK from my Android device?

Comment: building Android apps on your Android phone :-   http://www.androidauthority.com/building-android-apps-with-aide-671149/

Comment: I want to build something of my own as AIDE. What do i do ?

Comment: To get started, you can download AIDE from the Play Store, read the link I sent you.

Comment: "Can I run the gradlew command from my android phone on the terminal emulator with root access to compile an android project and generate an APK ?" -- not by default. Gradle requires a JDK. Android devices do not ship with a JDK. "What do i do ?" -- that is *far* beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow question. Getting [everything shown on this diagram](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-workflow), or even a subset, to run on an Android device would be a very complex task. It's doable (AIDE is proof), but it's not something that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: If we can find a way to put the JDK on the phone, where would my sdk location be on the phone and can gradle then be used ? @CommonsWare

Comment: "where would my sdk location be on the phone" -- I have no idea. "can gradle then be used ?" -- possibly. Gradle was not designed to be run on an Android device, but it runs on Linux. The `gradlew` shell script probably needs to be revised.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and develop your apps on android devices with DroidePro
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.einfachsoft.droide.pro

Comment: This is more of a suggestion than an answer